# anksvn checkin file

Tags: c#, svn

I am using the most recent version of anksvn for a visual studio 2008 project file. I now 
want to check this code into anksvn, but I am having a problem.

The situtation is, I checked in the most current version of code into anksvn. That is fine.

However I have another version of this code that I did not check out from subversion initially. This other copy of the code was for a 'demo' only. However now this code needs to become the production code. Thus I am trying to determine how to check this code into anksvn.

What I know I can do is to 'remove' the most curent code folder that is in anksvn. I could  then place this project folder into that location. since the origianl 'demo' code also  includes the current production code.

However I am trying to see if there is a better method to accomplish this goal. Could I possibly use the branch/switch option?

Answer (score 0):

Is the demo code checked out of Subversion at all? I know you didn't check it out, but was it checked out? If it was, you could commit this code back into Subversion, then update your working directory.

It his code has nothing to do with Subversion, you will have to take a more complex route: You will have to copy the changes manually to your code.

Since you're using Windows, you should take a look at [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), This is commercial code, but you can download a limited time demo for free -- more than enough time to handle your situation. I use Beyond Compare all the time to compare two different directories or Java jar files or zip archives, etc. It not only can quickly show you the differences, but makes it each to copy those differences from one to the other.

I have no relationship with Scooter software, the makers of Beyond Compare except as a customer.